# Ruby broken core methods?

Tags: ruby, hash

Here we go:

```
images = {:default=>["http://original-img", "http://original-img2"]}
img_src = ["http://localhost/image987.jpeg", "http://localhost/image988.jpeg"]
img_ids = [2046, 2047]

_images_src = images.clone
_images_src.each_value{|v| v.map!{img_src.shift}}
p _images_src # {:default=>["http://localhost/image987.jpeg", "http://localhost/image988.jpeg"]}

images.each_value{|v| v.map!{img_ids.shift}}
p images # {:default=>[2046, 2047]}
p _images_src # {:default=>[2046, 2047]}
```

How **each_value** call on images, changes the _images_src hash? They refer to different objects and _images_src IS CLONED images and still changes.

Comment: Hint: if you think that some of the most often used, most exercised core methods of a language implementation used by tens of thousands of people everyday are broken, and nobody of those tens of thousands of programmers has ever noticed in their tens of millions of lines of code, and you are the first one ever to notice it … you're probably wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've done a "shallow clone" but need a "deep clone." Search around for how to make that happen and what the tradeoffs are.  You can see this by running the below. Note the object ids are the same.

```
[8] pry(main)> @images.values.first.object_id
=> 70308363136840
[9] pry(main)> _images_src.values.first.object_id
=> 70308363136840
```

Comment: It depends on what you need to do and what you are cloning. There are several gems that address the issue in a variety of ways. Or you could adjust your approach on how `_images_src` gets created.

Comment: ruby life, Ruby's built-in [Marshal](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/Marshal.html) methods are often used to make deep copies of (most) Ruby objects: `obj_deep_copy = Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(obj))`.